What parameters of a material must i know to deduce its internal electromagnetic field?
In continuum physics, it is assumed that an open region in space $\Omega$ that contains a given substance has the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is isotropic and is homogeneous everywhere... But I think such a region should also contain an, at least, homogeneous electromagnetic field (due to the average acceleration of the molecules, i guess?!), provided it isn't accelerating. If this is the case, what properties of the substance contained in $\Omega$ should I know to describe the EM field inside $\Omega$?

Charge and current densities and the dielectric permitivity and magnetic permeability.

@agaminon Is that all? (Sorry if its trivial, i'm not a physicist)

It does not seem like much, but even with perfect knowledge about these quantities, solving Maxwell's equations is not trivial.
